# Is there a way to set scale value before fig up?

Tags: scale, docker, fig

If you scale a service 10x

```
fig scale www=10
```

then stop

```
fig stop
```

Fig will "cache" the amount of scaling, so next time i do

```
fig up
```

It will start already with 10x www.

Is there a way to avoid that?

At the moment if i try to set `scale` before doing `fig up` i get an error:

```
Starting xxx_www_1...
Cannot start container 7c8276e76ada36b183f1f9873abf4e28d4314227a1fa8980127763eb50c22700: 
Cannot link to a non running container: yyyy AS zzzz
```